# Text-overflow's compatibility in IE8 and firefox

Tags: css

here is the problem. I set text-overflow as :text-overflow:ellipsis. But it can't show in ellipsis when input text value beyond the length  that i set. Below is part code:

```
<td align="left" width="220px">
    <h:inputText id="id_NETypeInput" value="" style="width:200px;font-size:12px;align:left;text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);text-overflow:ellipsis;"
        styleClass="otEditField"
        onclick="#{rich:component('ruleTypeSelectPanel')}.show()" />
</td>
```

Any comments? Th.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `overflow: hidden;` and a maximum height and width on the element, in combination with `text-overflow: ellipsis`, this would show the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but make sure it will not work in every browser so keep in mind

```
/*id or class whatever or inline */{
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;                   
  overflow: hidden; /* "overflow" value must be different from "visible" */
  text-overflow:    ellipsis;
}
```

or if you want to more explore it here is link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/text-overflow
here is one more link for check compability of text-overflow
http://caniuse.com/text-overflow